# Parse chat not getting received messages

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

We are implementing a chat in our android application. We have an userlist and of you click on one of the users, you start a chat with that user. We can send messages to the database with the sender and receiver and we can load these messages everytime we open that specific chat. We cannot, however, get the messages that are sent to the user from the database. [This is how our Parse chat colums look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2qts.png)

This is our code for loading the conversation list:

```
private void loadConversationList()
{
    final ParseQuery<ParseObject> q = ParseQuery.getQuery("Chat");
    if (convList.size() == 0)
    {
        // load all messages...
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        al.add(buddy);
        al.add(UserList.user.getUsername());
        q.whereContainedIn("sender", al);
        q.whereContainedIn("receiver", al);
    }
    else
    {
        // load only newly received message..
        if (li != null && li.size() > 0)
            q.whereGreaterThan("createdAt", lastMsgDate);
        q.whereEqualTo("sender", buddy);
        q.whereEqualTo("receiver", UserList.user.getUsername());
    }
    q.orderByDescending("createdAt");
    q.setLimit(30);
    q.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>()
    {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> li, ParseException e)
        {
            if (li != null && li.size() > 0)
            {
                for (int i = li.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    ParseObject po = li.get(i);
                    Conversation c = new Conversation(po
                            .getString("message"), po.getCreatedAt(), po.getString("sender"));

                    convList.add(c);

                    f = li.size();

                    if (lastMsgDate == null
                            || lastMsgDate.before(c.getDate()))
                        lastMsgDate = c.getDate();
                    adp.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }

            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    if (isRunning)
                        loadConversationList();

                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    });



}
```

The conversation list is used to fill the screen with te messages. In SendMessage we also update the conversation list, only with the send messages of course. The problem is that the conversation list doesn't update the received messages

Comment: Have you isolated where the problem is?  I see several places where this could be failing, and that is the first step.

Comment: @nasch     We think the problem lies in the first bit of code where the parse query is made, because the list of parseobjects in the method done is only the length of the sent messages. So we think the query that is given to 'done' is incomplete. No idea why or how to fix it though.

Comment: And you've verified in the parse data browser that the data is being inserted as expected?